# Dynamically allocated multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I'm trying to define an array of strings using `malloc`, but some values return an Access Violation Error. As the whole program is extensive, I'm adding just the part where the matrix is declared:

```
int main(void)
{
    char* temp;
    char p[MAXSIZE];
    printf("This program lists the possible permutations of a character sequence\n");
    printf("Enter your sequence: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &p, MAXSIZE);
    temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(p)));
    int count[MAXSIZE / 2] = { 0 };
    char* y = checkforrepetition(p, count);
    char** u = malloc(sizeof(char) * possibilities(count,strlen(p))*MAXSIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i <= (possibilities(count,strlen(p)) - 1); i++)
    {
        u[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXSIZE);
    }
    recursivepermute(p, 0, temp, strlen(p), u, possibilities(count,strlen(p)));
}
```

I'm using `scanf_s` because Visual Studio requires me to do so.
I would like to know if the error is a problem with the declaration of the array itself or if there's an error somewhere else in the code.

A brief explanation is: The possibilities function returns the amount of combinations possible for the string provided by the user. The purpose of the array `u` is to store the permutations that have already been made, in order to avoid repetition of the same combination in strings with repeated characters.

Comment: Which exact line of code does the Access Violation trigger on?

Comment: The `scanf_s()` call looks OK except that you should pass `p` instead of `&p`.  However, it shouldn't be the cause of the trouble.

Comment: It is triggered on the for loop,that is supposed to determine the elements of the first array

Comment: OTOH, the call `temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(p)));` does not allocate enough space for the null byte at the end of the string; that could easily be a problem.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * possibilities(count,strlen(p))*MAXSIZE)` should have `sizeof(char *)` instead. Or even better `sizeof(*u)`

Comment: You probably should save the result of `possibilities(count, strlen(p))` in a local variable, rather than calling it many times.

Comment: `temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(p)))`, `sizeof (char)` is always `1` and can be omitted. If you expect to store a string of `strlen(p)` chars in `temp`, then you need to allocate `strlen(p) + 1` bytes (don't forget the *nul-terminating* character).

Answer (score 0):

1. Line 8: `temp` is not initialised. Try

   ```
   temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(p)+1));
   strcpy(temp,p);
   ```

   Note: `strlen()` returns number of characters from the beginning of the buffer until (excluding) the first null terminator `'\0'`, but `strcpy` copies everything including the first null terminator. Hence the `strlen(p) + 1` above.
2. Line 10: You don't seem to be using `char* y`? Make sure `checkforrepetition(p, count)` returns heap memory and clean-up `y` in main scope.
3. Line 11: malloc of double array `char** u` is wrong. The pattern is:

   ```
   //malloc the container
   char** stringArray = (char**)malloc(numberOfArrayElements * sizeof(char*));
   //malloc the elements
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArrayElements; i++)
   { 
     stringArray[i] = (char*)malloc((sizeOfElement + 1) * sizeof(char));
     strcpy(stringArray[i], "");
   }
   ```

   or equivalent shorthand (pointer arithmetic). Destruction follows the inverted steps (first the elements then the container). Your code could be:

   ```
   char** u = malloc(sizeof(char*) * possibilities(count,strlen(p)));
   for (int i = 0; i < possibilities(count,strlen(p)); i++)
   {
       u[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAXSIZE + 1));
   }
   ```